# href link not working in Widows environment, works fine in Eclipse . Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, href

I'm following a Spring boot tutorial application With a Spring Tool Suite(STS) ide. When is start the application in STS all the *links* work fine. Then I pack the application in a jar file and start it in the Windows environment, the application starts fine. But the *links* don't work.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/projects/list">Projects</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/employees/list">Employees</a>
```

I don't think it makes a different, but the links are in a layouts.html file inside a templates folder. Inside a navbar. I'm using a Thymeleaf template engine.

I get this error message:

> Error resolving template [/employees/employee-list], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.

Well, I know the template exist and work in Eclipse why wont they work in Windows? I the browser I get this message, for both links:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you unzip the jar file and check if the templates are really in the jar file?

Comment: Your link `href` is pointed to `/employees/list` location, but the error indicates Thymeleaf trying to get the template from `/employees/employee-list`. Probably the issue is in the `templateResolver.setPrefix`. Check what it's set to.